# Search unix word in line and if it is there then delete from that word to end of line

Tags: vim, grep, sed

My file contain following lines

File.txt

```
Unix is good
Linux and unix is different? 
Linux is also good,  then what about unix?
```

Here I want output

```
(1st line blank) 
Linix and
Linux is also good,  then what about
```

Here vi command or any other command will give this output? 
Search particular word if that is in line then delete that word and next all word in that line.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the word `unix` and all words that follow it on a line:

```
$ sed 's/[uU]nix.*//' File.txt

Linux and 
Linux is also good,  then what about
```

`s` signifies a *substitute* command.  In this command sed matches the regex `[uU]nix.*` and replaces it with an empty string. `[uU]nix` matches either `Unix` or `unix`.  `.*` matches everything that follows.

#### Variations

The following will also delete any blanks that precedes `unix`:

```
sed 's/ *[uU]nix.*//' File.txt
```

The following will delete not just blanks that precede `unix` but tabs or any other whitespace that precede `unix`:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*[uU]nix.*//' File.txt
```

`[:space:]` matches any whitespace and is unicode-safe.

The following deletes the preceding whitespace but will also match any capitalization of `unix` such as `Unix`, `uNix`, `uNIX`, etc:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*unix.*//I' File.txt
```

`I` tells sed to match in a case-insensitive way.  Because this is a GNU extension, this version of the command will not be portable to MacOS or BSD.